How to draw percentage on bar graph by javascript
I have this very useful chart, but my problem is that the client wants to display percentage label.
I have attached image below of what I want:

<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<body>

<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
const xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
const yValues = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];
const barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown"];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wine Production 2018"
    }
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>


You can use onComplete hook to draw/write these values after chart animation is fully rendered. And then use ctx.fillText() to customise how you prefer.
const xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina"];
const yValues = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15];
const barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown"];
const total = yValues.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wine Production 2018"
    },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function () {
        const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
          for (let i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
const model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
            ctx.fillText("%", model.x + 15, model.y - 5);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

UPDATE
I don't know if I understand you correctly. I assume you want to add new data to the chart... If so, you then need to update the arrays. Correlate data with bar and color values. I assume this is what you mean when a client wants to add something. And then update dataset array.
const xValues = ["Italy", "France", "Spain", "USA", "Argentina", "New1", "New2"];
const yValues = [55, 49, 44, 24, 15, 12, 99];
const barColors = ["red", "green","blue","orange","brown", "bronze", "purple"];
const total = yValues.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: yValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "World Wine Production 2018"
    },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function () {
        const ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
          for (let i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            const model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 5);
            ctx.fillText("%", model.x + 15, model.y - 5);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/QWRKMNX?authentication_hash=xnMabpeVanRr

why not working if i try to add another set of graph

@jhunlio Edit your first post with code, please. Because can be several reason by that e.g. scope, id etc.

is there anyway i can duplicate it?

@jhunlio just “edit” your first post, simply switch old code on code with issue…

I edit this part new Chart("myChart", { to this new Chart("tvq", { but it's not working

can you give me sample code please on how to duplicate the graph please

@jhunlio Look at update, I assume that you talking about…

actually I want is duplicate the entire chart or another set of chart but you already answer my posted question thank you so much.

i mean multiple chart in same page is that posible\

To show the percentage on the top of each bar, you can use the datalabel plugin with your charts. It helps to add the Y-Axis actual count on the top of each bar. Even, you can modify its behavior too.
Giving an example link, from where you can also get a better understanding of it. [Video Link]
